# How can I pull specific value from my table using WHERE and AND based on another specific value?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having an issue pulling specific data using a WHERE and AND command in my SELECT statement. This issue is as follows:

I have a table called "solo_leaderboard". It is within this table that I store high score values for all games in a game club. I would like to keep all of the high scores in this table as creating a separate table for each game seems ridiculous. I use this table to populate HTML pages displaying the Top 5 scores for each game. A person may only have one score in the Top 5 for each game at a time. So far this part works great.

My main issue is that my code is pulling only a person's high score from the entire table and displaying it only if it is applicable to the said game. For example, a person has a top score of 3111 in Sega Dreamcast's Crazy Taxi so their high score of 18 in Atari's Freeway is not displayed in the Freeway list even though they would be in second place on the Freeway list.

I don't want a person to be on the same leaderboard for multiple times, but I do want them to appear on other leaderboards.

Here is my table schema and respective php code:

- id - int(10)
- gamesystem - varchar(30)
- game - varchar(30)
- name - varchar(40)
- score - int(10)
- date - date
- gradelevel - varchar(5)
- whois - enum

> ```
>  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard x WHERE game 
>     LIKE '%Freeway%' AND score >= ALL
>         (SELECT score FROM solo_leaderboard y
>             WHERE y.name=x.name
>               AND score>0) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5");
> ```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard x WHERE game 
    LIKE '%Freeway%' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5` - is this not all you need? What doesn't work when you use it?

Comment: That works great if I was okay with repeats on the leaderboard. If person A holds the top 3 scores on the same leaderboard I only want to see their top score. I have found that a student who is especially good can fill up the top 5 spots all by themself and I like having other students on the list.

Comment: Oh I see - I misunderstood, I thought the table only contained the highest score by each player for each game. Does it actually contain all scores ever recorded? In that case you can do it with `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: by which I mean something like: `SELECT name, MAX(score) AS 'max_score' FROM solo_leaderboard x WHERE game LIKE '%Freeway%' ORDER BY (MAX(score)) GROUP BY name LIMIT 5`. (Apologies if that's not exactly right, I'm not great at SQL, but something like this ought to work. I'm sure others will correct me if that's wrong :) )

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of "AND game LIKE '%Freeway%' at the end of my nested SELECT statement, I have effectively solved the problem.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard x WHERE game LIKE '%Freeway%' AND score >= ALL    (SELECT score FROM solo_leaderboard y
        WHERE y.name=x.name
          AND score>0 AND game LIKE '%Freeway%') ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5");
```